# Boas práticas para alterar variáveis $scope

Tags: angularjs

Segue um exemplo de código:

Controller:

```
$scope.filterText = {status: 'Todos', tipo: 'Todos'};
$scope.params = {page: 1, total: 10, orderBy: 'id', sort: 'desc', search: {status: '',tipo: ''}};

$scope.filterStatus = function(status, text) {
    $scope.params.search.status = status;
    $scope.filterText.status = text;
    getProjetos($scope.params);
};

$scope.filterTipo = function(tipo, text) {
    $scope.params.search.tipo = tipo;
    $scope.filterText.tipo = text;
    getProjetos($scope.params);
};
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="filterStatus(1, 'Execução')">Status: {{filterText.status}}</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="filterTipo(1, 'Laboratório')">Tipo: {{filterText.tipo}}</a>
```

Para alterar os textos dos botões e os parâmetros da query eu faço a atribuição de dentro da função sem passar por parâmetro, alterando diretamente o $scope, mas não deve ser uma boa prática.

Eu altero o `$scope.params` porque quero que fique salvo o estado da query, por exemplo se eu clicar nos dois botões, o primeiro seta o `$scope.params.status = 1` e faz a busca, quando clicar no segundo seta o `$scope.params.tipo = 1` e faz a busca, mantendo ainda o `$scope.params.status = 1` nessa segunda busca.

Quais são as boas práticas para alterar variáveis `$scope` e qual a melhor solução nessa situação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sua implementação tenta controlar o fluxo de eventos programaticamente e de maneira síncrona (`filterStatus` > armazena `status` e `texto` > `getProjetos()`).

Você pode se beneficiar da natureza assíncrona do JavaScript e o comportamento *dual binding* do Angular, simplificando assim tanto seu processo quanto seu código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.selected = {};                     // Armazena a seleção do usuário
  $scope.statuses = [1,2,3,4,5]             // Possíveis estados
  $scope.tipos = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];      // Possíveis tipos

  $scope.$watch('selected', function(val) { // Monitora mudanças 
                                            // no valor de $scope.selected

    console.log('A seleção mudou:', val);   // Ou, no seu caso, chame 
                                            // getProjetos();
  }, true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>

    Status: 
    <select ng-model="selected.status">
      <option ng-repeat="s in statuses" value="{{s}}">{{s}}</option>
    </select>

    Tipo: 
    <select ng-model="selected.tipo">
      <option ng-repeat="t in tipos" value="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
    </select>

    <br>

    {{selected }}

  </div>
</div>
```